# Is it safe to remove completely keyrings from Ubuntu?

Tags: security, keyrings

To be honest I didn't like how keyrings work in Ubuntu and removed them completely.

Is my action safe and won't it harm any part of the system?

Comment: Keyrings are one of those things which reduce the PITA. Wouldn't know why someone wouldn't like them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Keyrings** are only made to **store passwords** so that you don't have to always type them. It will do **no harm** to delete them except for the hassle of typing them all again.